# Text file encoding scheme

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, vi

How do applications (eg. vim) know which format (i.e. ASCII, unicode, etc.) the given text file is in before they read it?

Also how can we write say a C++ a program to detect the same?

Comment: In 2015, it's *relatively* safe to assume *every* file is UTF-8. (This was not the case 10-15 years ago)

Comment: Yes but there has to be some sort of way for applications to figure that out correct?

Comment: @immibis The standard behaviour of applications on Windows is still to use the local codepage (usually labeled as *ANSI*) by default.

Comment: @roeland Yes, and in 2015, it's still relatively safe to assume *every* file is UTF-8. Even files created on Windows are more likely than not to be UTF-8. Even though that's not WIndows's default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They generally don't know before they read it. Sometimes they don't know ever after they read it--most look at the beginning of the file, and try to guess at the encoding of the data it contains.

In some cases, that can be pretty easy (e.g., if it starts with a Unicode BOM) but in others fairly difficult. At one time, Microsoft's "IsTextUnicode" made bad guesses for a fair amount of English text, so Notepad (for one program that used it) would let you type one thing into a file, then when you opened the file again, it would show you something entirely different, because the English you entered was being interpreted as Chinese characters encoded in Unicode.

Comment: So there is no way for any program to know?

Comment: Thanks! The mystery that is unicode continues ... I will just assume that it is "something" and continue with my life